# About a criteria for random integers number generation (C)

Tags: c, random

I am running a bunch of physical simulations in which I need random numbers. I'm using the standard `rand()` function in C++.

So it works like this: first I precalculate a bunch of probabilities that are of the form `1/(1+exp(a))`, for a set of different `a`. They're of type `double` as returned by the `exp` function in the `math` library, and then things must happen with those probabilities, there are only two of them, so I generate a random number uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 and compared with those precalculated probabilities. To do that, I used:

```
double p = double(rand()%101)/100.0;
```

so I'm given random values between `0` and `1` both included. This didn't yield to correct physical results. I tried this:

```
double p = double(rand()%1000001)/1000000.0;
```

And this worked. I don't really understand why so I would like some criteria about how to do it. My intuition tells that if I do

```
double p = double(rand()%(N+1))/double(N);
```

with `N` big enough such that the smallest division (`1/N`) is much smaller than the smallest probability `1/1+exp(a)` then I will be getting realistic random numbers.

I would like to understand why, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand()` returns a random number between 0 and RAND_MAX.

Therefore you need this:

```
double p = double(rand() % RAND_MAX) / double(RAND_MAX);
```

Also run this snippet and you will understand:

```
  int i;

  for (i = 1; i < 30; i++)
  {
      int rnd = rand();
      double p0 = double(rnd % 101) / 100.0;
      double p1 = double(rnd % 1000001) / 1000000.0;
      printf ("%d\t%f\t%f\n", rnd, p0, p1);
  }

  for (i = 1; i < 30; i++)
  {
      int rnd = rand();
      double p0 = double(rnd) / double(RAND_MAX);
      printf ("%d\t%f\n", rnd, p0);
  }
```

Comment: Hmm that would obviously give the best result. Thank you

Comment: BTW: `double(rand()%1000001)/1000000.0;` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems.

1. `rand()` isn't very random at all. On almost all operating systems it returns badly distributed, horribly biased numbers. It's actually quite hard to find a good random number generator, but I can guarantee you that `rand()` will be among the worst you can find.
2. `rand() % N` gives a biased distribution. Think about the pigeonhole principle. Let's simplify it, assume that rand returns numbers [0,7) and your N is 6. 0 to 5 map to 0 to 5, 6 maps to 0 and 7 maps to 1, meaning that 0 and 1 are twice as likely to come out.
3. Converting the numbers to double before division *does not* remove the bias from 2, it just makes it less visible. The pigeonhole principle applies regardless of the conversions you do.
4. Converting a well-distributed random number from integer to float/double is harder than it looks. Simple division ignores the problems of how floating point math works.

I can't help you much with `1`, you need to do research. Look around the net for random number libraries. If you want something very random and unpredictable you need to look for cryptographic random libraries. If you want a repeatable but good random number Mersenne Twister should probably be good enough. But you need to do the research here.

For 2 and 3 there are standard solutions. You are mapping a set from M elements to N elements and `rand % N` will only work iff N < M and N and M share prime factors. Since on most systems M will be a power of two it means that N also has to be a power of two. So assuming that M is a power of two the algorithm is: find the nearest power of 2 higher or equal to N, let's call it P. Generate `randomness_source() % P`. If the number is higher than N, throw it away and try again. This is the only safe way to do this. Cleverer people than you and me have spent years on this problem, there's no better way to remove the bias.

For 4, you can probably ignore the problem and just divide, in an absolute majority of cases this should be good enough. If you really want to study the problem, I've done some work on it and published the code [on github.](https://github.com/art4711/random-double) There I go through some basic principles of how floating point numbers work and how it relates to generating random numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As for points 1 and 4 I will do some research. As for point 2, I was aware of it, but the bias will be, in this case, of the order M mod N, so the bias is zero if M is a multiple of N (ovbiously). Now, if N is very small, this bias will be practically zero: for example rand()%2 has a bias of 1/Rand_Max if rand_max is odd, as it's choosing from a set of N+1,N, with N being of the order of rand_max/2. In this case 100 would be much smaller than rand_max, am I right? Again, thank you for your help

Comment: You could calculate the bias, but why? It's so simple to just not have any bias at all and it's good practice whenever your initial assumptions change. Here's a free implementation of a function that gives you uniformly distributed numbers from a randomness source that returns [0,2^32) (it uses a faster, but harder to explain algorithm than the one I mentioned): http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/lib/libc/crypt/arc4random_uniform.c?rev=1.1&content-type=text/plain

Comment: If I didn't know any other methods I might at least know how big the errors are going to be because of random bias :D. I will have a look at that. Thank you!

Comment: Btw. You made me look at this kind of problems again. And you're not alone in having problems with this. The C++11 mandated uniform_real_distribution in both llvm and gcc are both badly implemented and get a very biased distribution, I wrote a post about it: http://www.blahonga.org/2015/04/state-of-art-of-random-double-generation.html People keep forgetting that floating point numbers don't behave like numbers we learned in school.

Comment: That's a bit of a relief. I tried a few different random number generators, since rand() to mersenne twister to two others I found and I got the same numerical results for my work using all of them, so I guess that to the extent of my work the generation of random numbers is fine. That's weird because there is an actual bias in some of them at least, so I guess it's compensating with some other bias, and that the final distributions in the intervals I use is actually uniform.

Answer (score 0):

```
// produces pseudorandom bits.  These are NOT crypto quality bits.  Has the same underlying unpredictability as uncooked
// rand() output.  It buffers rand() bits to produce a more convenient zero-to-the-argument range including negative
// arguments, corrects for the toward-zero bias of the modular construction I'd be using otherwise, eliminates the
// RAND_MAX range limitation, (use INT64_MAX instead) and effectively obscures biases and sequence telltales due to
// annoyingly bad rand libraries.  It does not correct these biases; anyone tracking the arguments and outputs has
// enough information to reconstruct the rand() output and detect them.  But it makes the relationships drastically more complicated.

// needs stdint, stdlib.

int64_t privaterandom(int64_t range, int reset){
    static uint64_t state = 0;
    int64_t retval;
    if (reset != 0){
       srand((unsigned int)range);
       state = (uint64_t)range;
    }
    if (range == 0) return (0);
    if (range < 0) return -privaterandom(-range, 0);
    if (range > UINT64_MAX/0xFFFFFFFF){
       retval = (privaterandom(range/0xFFFFFFFF, 0) * 0xFFFFFFFF); // order of operations matters
       return (retval + privaterandom(0xFFFFFFFF, 0));
    }
    while (state < UINT64_MAX / 0xFF){
       state *= RAND_MAX;
       state += rand();
    }
    retval = (state % range);
    // makes "pigeonhole" bias alternate unpredictably between toward-even and toward-odd
    if ((state/range > (state - (retval) )/ range) && state % 2 == 0) retval++; 
    state /= range;
    return retval;
}
int64_t Random(int64_t range){ return (privaterandom(range, 0));}
int64_t Random_Init(int64_t seed){return (privaterandom(seed, 1));}
```